# PyCharm Tutorial , While Loop

Tags: python

```
square = 0
number = 1

while number < 10:
    square = number ** 2
    print(square)
    number += 1
```

It's my answer for this question :" Print all squares from 0 to 99(1,4,..,81)Use number variable in while loop."
Pycharm says it doesn't match with its answer.
I think i should print those numbers in a single line but i couldn't deal with it.How can i do that ?

Comment: *I think i should print those numbers in a single line*, you don't know? I don't really see a question here, what is not working?

Comment: This code runs. What are you trying to ask exactly?

Comment: Pycharm says it doesn't match with its answer , i mean it tries to say : user should print those numbers in a single line (1,4,9,16....).I ask how can i do that ?

Comment: Please be more specific on the print format, beyond "in a single line." Do you want those parentheses surrounding all the values? Do you want just commas between values, or a comma and a space? Also, so you want all that formatting done in printing, or can it be done with strings such as using the `join` method?

Comment: @Gingerbread Are you writing test cases for this and your test cases are failing?

Comment: I don't want anything :D I just wrote all things that program asked me probably it should be like this : 1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64,81

Comment: @Gingerbread,again, *probably it should be like this* makes no sense, how do you not know, is the *computer* making you guess?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham i will try these thanks , I couldn't understand what the computer means.I wrote the question above , anyway it is not a big deal thank you btw

Comment: @RoryDaulton tristan explained it thank you , as you said with join method :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will `print` each number in a newline, because, in Python, the call to `print()` comes with an [implicit newline (see the `end` argument per the documentation)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=print#print).

Next, you're making an assumption about output formatting.  As I see it, there are two primary issues with this assumption:

1) Calls to functions (e.g. `print()`) in a `while` loop "execute" when they're called -- there's no delay to see if a future pass through the loop will provide extra data to the function.

2) You're assuming that the Python interpreter will guess that printed numbers (in a while loop) are desired to be returned in a comma separated list.  Computers are machines that do what you tell them to do -- if you don't write logic to explain what you need, the machine cannot give you this.

You can express your desired output in the following ways:

1) Collect the numbers (as strings) in a list, then output them after you're done looping:

```
square = 0
number = 1

# think of this as a result container
number_result_list = []

while number < 10:
    square = number ** 2
    # place that number at the end of your container:
    number_result_list.append(str(square))
    number += 1

# join all your number strings together, using a comma
print(",".join(number_result_list))

# prints 1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64,81
```

2) Specify that you want to use a comma in the call to print.  Make special note of the trailing comma -- you now know why this happens:

```
square = 0
number = 1

while number < 10:
    square = number ** 2
    print(square, end=",")
    number += 1

# prints 1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64,81,
```

Comment: Thank you soo much , you are the hero !!

Comment: You're very welcome.  As you're new to SO, I want to give you the "head's up" that it's customary -- and completely optional -- to accept answers if they've solved your question.